# How can i retrieve the data (name,uid,post.....) from the following firebase db for my web application using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase DB]

This is the code. It contains both HTML and javascript.
This code doesn't have any effect. It's showing nothing.
The DB actually created using the Android app. Now I have to retrieve these data in my web app too.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        var config = {
            apiKey: "PlhWdY7OVtZGhBAEI_LrGMP073D5Ra6g",
            authDomain: "m-grance.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://m-grance.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "m-grievance",
            storageBucket: "m-grance.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "57976764514788"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        function fun(){
            var rootRef = firebase.database.ref();
            var urlRef = rootRef.child("User/123456788765/name");
            urlRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                    console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="fun()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is trying to read a node at *User/123456788765/name* which doesn't exist in your example structure (the parent node key is different). Also, even if it were the same, it would read the value *testname* because you are only reading the *name* child node. Check out the [Getting Started; Read and write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) guide on their website - it's a good read.

Comment: @NewToJS it didnt worked